# c# first Radio Button in control group 1 does nothing

Tags: c#, radio-button

in c# I have 2 group boxes with 3 radio buttons of primary color choices (red, blue, and yellow). I have it set that when I click a button called Mix it takes the choices from the radio buttons and changes the form background color. i.e blue and yellow selected button click makes form background green, blue and blue makes background blue etc. My problem is that when I click the radio button called rdbRed in group box 1 and select any of the other colors from group box 2 it does nothing. No error codes just nothing.  The values for it and other buttons are set exactly the same, and this is the only button that does nothing. In the code it is rdbRed. I have deleted it and recreated it, all other buttons and button combinations work fine.

```
namespace Color_Mixer

public partial class frmMixer : Form

    public frmMixer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnMix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbRed.Checked && rdbRed2.Checked || rdbRed2.Checked && rdbRed.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (rdbRed.Checked && rdbBlue1.Checked || rdbBlue1.Checked && rdbRed2.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Purple;
        }
        else if (rdbRed.Checked && rdbYellow1.Checked || rdbYellow1.Checked && rdbRed2.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (rdbBlue1.Checked && rdbBlue2.Checked || rdbBlue2.Checked && rdbBlue1.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (rdbBlue1.Checked && rdbYellow2.Checked || rdbYellow1.Checked && rdbBlue2.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (rdbYellow1.Checked && rdbYellow2.Checked || rdbYellow2.Checked && rdbYellow1.Checked)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Any simple thoughts or suggestions I might have missed would be appreciated and I don't want to recode everything. Also, we haven't gone as far as try.parse or anything like that.

Thanks,
D

Comment: Advise(just) to improve your code quality ' rdbRed.Checked' is same as ' rdbRed.Checked == true ', Use a consistent style

Comment: May it be that you accidentally have a `rdbRed` and a `rdbRed1` and access the wrong radio button? The name for this button differs from the other ones.

Comment: That was actually after I recreated it because even as rdbRed1 the first button was doing nada.

Comment: since you have 2 group boxes each with 3 radio buttons, total combinations will be 9. But you have written only 6 if else statements. May be you are missing on conditions.

Comment: I thought the || was an or specifying 2 conditions that would end with the same result color? it works on every other button just not the first one. It's actually 6 ifs with 2 possible trues (blue and blue would make the background blue).

Comment: check your code properly. You have used rdbRed in only first 3 if conditions in combination with the other radio buttons from group box 1. No combinations from group box 2. I think thats the reason.

Comment: the or || in each of the if else works for every other button in group 1. the radio buttons ending in 1 are from group 1 with exception of rdbRed because I recreated it (after it wasn't working to begin with) and didn't re-ad the 1. the radio button selections from group 2 end with a 2

Comment: Nilesh is right. You have to adapt the first parts of conditions 2 and 3 to rdbBlue2 and rdbYellow2. And for colors red blue and yellow the second parts of the conditions are redundant.

Comment: Saw a typo checking it now. Nilesh was correct to say check the code. Not sure if he/she saw the same error but in a few of the statements, I had it set to have red from group 1 and one of the other colors from group 1.

Comment: I recreated the rdbRed renamed it to rdbRed1 and changed the lines else if (rdbRed.Checked && rdbBlue1.Checked  <--- both group 1 buttons  //// else if (rdbRed.Checked && rdbYellow1.Checked   <---- also both group 1 buttons   sometimes just another set of eyes is all that's needed   Thanks Nilesh and everyone else!

Comment: By the way it's terrible code :-) Just use `bool red = rdbRed.Checked || rdbRed2.Checked;` and so on for `bool blue` and `bool yellow`. Then `if(red && yellow) color = Color.Orange`.

Comment: Yeah haven't got that far in instruction yet. Will do some research on it though.

Comment: if (rdbRed.Checked && rdbRed2.Checked || rdbRed2.Checked && rdbRed.Checked) --> Reversing the order won't make it any truer!